# RuntimeError: Unknown qengine?The code is written correctly, but there is a problem, why and how to solve it?

Tags: python

```
import torch
import sounddevice as sd
import time

language = "ru"
model_id = "ru_v3"
sample_rate = 48000
speaker = "baya"
put_accent = True
put_yo = True
device = torch.device('cpu')
text = "Здраствуй Олег, рад знакомству"

model, _ = torch.hub.load(repo_or_dir='snakers4/silero-models',
                          model='silero_tts',
                          language=language,
                          speaker=model_id
                          )
model.to(device)

audio = model.apply_tts(text=text,
                        speaker=speaker,
                        sample_rate=sample_rate,
                        put_accent=put_accent,
                        put_yo=put_yo)

print(text)

sd.play(audio, sample_rate)
time.sleep(len(audio) / sample_rate)
sd.stop()
```

Error message:

```
Using cache found in C:\Users\User/.cache\torch\hub\snakers4_silero-models_master
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Voice_Assistent2/main.py", line 14, in <module>
    model, _ = torch.hub.load(repo_or_dir='snakers4/silero-models',
  File "D:\Voice_Assistent2\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 399, in load
    model = _load_local(repo_or_dir, model, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Voice_Assistent2\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 428, in _load_local
    model = entry(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User/.cache\torch\hub\snakers4_silero-models_master\src\silero\silero.py", line 88, in silero_tts
    model = imp.load_pickle("tts_models", "model")
  File "D:\Voice_Assistent2\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\package\package_importer.py", line 249, in load_pickle
    result = unpickler.load()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\pickle.py", line 1210, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\pickle.py", line 1251, in load_binpersid
    self.append(self.persistent_load(pid))
  File "D:\Voice_Assistent2\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\package\package_importer.py", line 227, in persistent_load
    loaded_reduces[reduce_id] = func(self, *args)
  File "D:\Voice_Assistent2\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\jit\_script.py", line 344, in unpackage_script_module
    cpp_module = torch._C._import_ir_module_from_package(
RuntimeError: Unknown qengine
```

Comment: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/getting-unknown-qengine-error-when-using-quantized-model-in-a-vm/111283/2

Comment: I suspect the issue has to do with either a missing or broken dependency. Looks like the previous comment has a link that hints out at what the issue might be. Make sure you have met all the minimum requirements for using pytorch.